# Error occurred during SQL insertion

Tags: php, email

I have tried this code to send a file and insert the details about the mail to a table:

```
<?php
session_start();
define('incall', true);
include("connection.php");

if(!@include_once('config.php'))
{
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    exit;
}

$to=$_POST['to'];
$message    = str_replace('{link}', $download_path.$_POST['filename'].'.mp3', $email_body);
$headers  = "From: ".$_POST['from'];
$subject=$_POST['subject'];
$date=date("Y/m/d");
$size='';
$username=$_SESSION['username']
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
{   
    $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO sent values('$username', '$to','$date', '', '.mp3', '$size' )");
    header("location:mailsent.php");
}
else
    exit('Error! VoiceMail not be send.');
?>
```

But I got some errors saying:

> HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server
>   Error): An unexpected condition was
>   encountered while the server was
>   attempting to fulfill the request.

Please help me

Comment: Have you access to the error log?

Comment: I wish there was a "warning: sql injection possible" button... @OP: Please post more details, e.g. what does your webserver error logs say?

Comment: $username=$_SESSION['username'] missing semicolon here

Comment: Put this code after $query to debug your sql: die($query);

Comment: It says [12-Mar-2011 11:14:45] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_IF in /home/mggs/public_html/vo/sendmail.php on line 19

Comment: then, it's a PHP syntax error, check your syntax carefully.

Comment: Also can you people please help me how to find the size of the file uploaded to the server ??? In the code, you can find the filename. Please help. Also for the current time, what should I give in the query instead of the blank space ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$username=$_SESSION['username']` missing `semicolon` here

Filesize :

use `filesize($_FILE['uploaderName']['tmp_name']);`

Comment: Also can you people please help me how to find the size of the file uploaded to the server ??? In the code, you can find the filename. Please help. Also for the current time, what should I give in the query instead of the blank space ?

Comment: how to find the current time ??

Comment: Also my file will be in the directory: example.com/upload/1245246235.mp3. So how can I correct this syntax ?? $size=filesize($_FILES['filename']['tmp']);

Comment: just give path of file `$download_path.$_POST['filename'].'.mp3'` instead of $_FILES['filename']['tmp']